# cast discards qualifiers from pointer target type?

Tags: c, gcc

`-Wcast-qual` outputs this warning on stristr()'s `return` line. What is the problem ?

> warning: cast discards qualifiers from pointer target type

```c
char *stristr(const char *string, const char *substring)
{
size_t stringlength = strlen(string);
char *stringlowered = malloc(stringlength + 1);
strcpy(stringlowered, string);
tolower2(stringlowered); // in my source it has a different name, sorry.

char *substringlowered = malloc(strlen(substring) + 1);
strcpy(substringlowered, substring);
tolower2(substringlowered); // in my source it has a different name, sorry.

const char *returnvalue = strstr(stringlowered, substringlowered);
if(returnvalue != NULL)
{
    size_t returnvaluelength = strlen(returnvalue);
    returnvalue = string;
    returnvalue += stringlength - returnvaluelength;
}

free(stringlowered);
free(substringlowered);

return (char *)returnvalue;
}
```

**EDIT :**
In glibc 2.15's strstr() source code:

```c
return (char *) haystack_start; // cast to (char *) from const char *
```

Comment: You may want to check to see if your platform doesn't already have `strcasestr()` available for you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have declared `returnvalue` as a pointer to a `const char`, but then you've cast it to a pointer to non-`const char`.  You've discarded the `const` qualifier, so the compiler complains that you've discarded it!

The solution is either to change the return type of the function, or to find a non-`const char` to point at.  You don't have one in your function, so you could consider changing the argument type if you *really* need a non-`const` return type.

Comment: The prototype is exactly the same as standard C's strstr() source code which throws tons of `discards qualifiers` warnings. I guess the only solutions is to make `string` not `const`.

Comment: @NigelRidley: Well, there's no one standard C implementation, but I imagine the core of most C libraries were implemented well before language standardisation had occurred.  Hence the questionable code if you look to deep!  It's also worth bearing in mind that the libraries are usually written by the compiler authors, so they're free to make all sorts of kludges that would otherwise be questionable/implementation-defined/undefined.

Answer (score 5):

You are casting a `const char *` (let's call it non-modifiable string) to a `char *` (modifiable string) you discard the `const` qualifier.

Comment: you should probably change the return value to `const char *` and remove the casting.

Comment: The prototype is exactly the same as standard C's strstr().

Comment: @Nigel: standard C's `strstr()` will do the same cast away of `const` that you do - it's just that the library doesn't get compiled during your build, so the warning there is long gone (actually I'm sure it's not even enabled for the build of the library).  You may need to disable this particular warning when building your `stristr()` function if you want it to have the same property that the standard library has of returning a non-const pointer into a string that had a const-pointer (and therefore placing the responsibility on the user to avoid doing the wrong thing with the pointer).

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the declaration/assignment

```
const char *returnvalue = strstr(stringlowered, substringlowered);
```

to

```
char *returnvalue = strstr(stringlowered, substringlowered);
```

and then remove the cast in the return line (you don't need it anymore).